# Why my Node.js application do not show on desktop after installation on Mac?

Tags: node.js, macos

I downloaded Node.js from the official website. After I install it, I can't find the application icon to run it. I am on MacOS.

Comment: I'm confused; what do you think NodeJS is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed the .pkg from https://nodejs.org/en/download/, then you should not expect to get any gui for running node. Node should be available for you to use in the terminal. You can open up a terminal and run `node -v` to confirm this. If it displays the version of node installed, then all is okay.

If you would say exactly what you needed running a gui node for then I may update this answer to better guide you.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. I am completely new in programming. How can I open a terminal to confirm it?

Comment: https://imgur.com/Fmgxy7n that looks like what you have said or am I wrong?

Comment: yeah, that's the terminal you opened. You can type node -v to confirm that node is installed. To run node, just type node in the terminal and enter.

Comment: If your node program is in a js file, just type node path_to_node_file where path_to_node_file is the path to your js file you want to run. You may also want to accept my answer as correct :)

Comment: thank you very much. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Node JS is only available via your command line and not via a GUI. As long as you have installed node js successfully, you can verify that It's working fine by running `node -v` or `npm -v`  in your terminal.